# Error during mysqld service installation on windows

Tags: mysql

I start mysqld from a windows console with the following command:

> "c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install MySQL --defaults-file=c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\my.ini

The service aborts. The log file display:

[ERROR] c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\bin\mysqld: unknown option '--install'

What could be the error ?

[EDIT]
The good syntax is:

> "c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --install MySQL --defaults-file="c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\my.ini"

The official documentation is wrong ...

Comment: The quotes are, of course, necessary around the `c:\program files\mysql\mysql server 5.5\my.ini` option - only because of the spaces you have in between the words.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was using the Powershell. So the fix for me was simple using CMD.

Answer (score -1):

Try specifying the option as:

```
--install=MySQL
```